# How to create Triples from MySql

Tags: mysql, marklogic, triples

I have used the d2rq utility to create .ttl files and then have imported it in MarkLofgic but unable to get the desired results.

Moreover my data looks like this.[image: Triples generated by d2rq]

How can I create Triples from MySql Data to be used for Querying in SPARQL in MarkLogic. SOmeone suggested that I should Consider Primary key values as subject, column names as Predicates & cell values as objects to convert into triples, but How ? 
Thanks & Regards
Swapneel GOLAPKAR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are showing there, are triples in the format that MarkLogic stores them in the database. Make sure to enable the `triple index` from Admin ui for that database to be able to use SPARQL on them.

Once enabled you can run commands like `count(cts:triples())` from QConsole to see how many triples have been loaded, and run SPARQL from there as well.

You can also connect to the `/v1/graphs/sparql` [REST endpoint](http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/graphs/sparql).

Regarding how data should look as triples, given two sample records like below (expressed as XML for convenience):

```
<Drug_Dtl>
    <Drug_ID>D001</Drug_ID>
    <Drug_name>Glyburide 5 mg</Drug_name>
    <Brand_name>Diabeta</Brand_name>
    <Brand>Novo Nordisk</Brand>
    <strength>5 mg</strength>
    <NoOfPills>1</NoOfPills>
    <TotalDailyDose>5 mg</TotalDailyDose>
    <Cost>$51</Cost>
    <DailyPills>1</DailyPills>
</Drug_Dtl>

<Prescriber>
    <PrescriberId>PSC001</PrescriberId>
    <PrescriberName>Wa&#x200C;&#x200B;yne</PrescriberName>
    <Prescriber_Address>7 Elgar Center</Prescriber_Address>
    <City>Chicago</City>
    <State>Illinois</State>
</Prescriber>
```

I would expect triples similar to (expressed as turtle for convenience):

```
<D001> <Drug_name> "Glyburide 5 mg".
<D001> <Brand_name> "Diabeta".
<D001> <Brand> "Novo Nordisk".
<D001> <strength> "5 mg".
<D001> <NoOfPills> "1".
<D001> <TotalDailyDose> "5 mg".
<D001> <Cost> "$51".
<D001> <DailyPills> "1".

<PSC001> <PrescriberName> "Wa&#x200C;&#x200B;yne".
<PSC001> <Prescriber_Address> "7 Elgar Center".
<PSC001> <City> "Chicago".
<PSC001> <State> "Illinois".
```

HTH!

Comment: I have enabled the triple Index in Admin Console as well can see the links of all the populated triples on /v1/graphs/things on the REST API, but my issue is I am unable to have the triples in that form like Primary Key as Subject, Columns as Predicate and Cells as Objects as told by you previously, and I suppose thats why its filling up the tags by <subject> instead of <actual value of subject(Primary Key)>. 
I am using d2rq mapping utility to create ttl file to be uploaded using mlcp. Plz suggest what I shall do! Thanks for your kind help :)

 Regards Swapneel

Comment: I think that depends on how you configured d2rq. Unfortunately, I know insufficient about your original data model to assess the quality of the triples, but it looks reasonable to me at first glance..

Comment: Ok I shall share the cooked data with you tomorrow so that it would be easy for you to understand me thanks a ton, may I plz know ur name.

Comment: I need to share the data with you, how do I do it? shall I mail it to u? theres no option of attachment here :(

Comment: No need to share all data, nor all tables. Just enough to get an impression. If small enough, you can just insert into the question.

Comment: The following is the data(Its only one row converted into xml for two tables)

Drug Table: 
Drug_Dtl><Drug_ID>D001</Drug_ID><Drug_name>Glyburide 5 mg</Drug_name><Brand_name>Diabeta</Brand_name><Brand>Novo Nordisk</Brand><strength>5 mg</strength><NoOfPills>1</NoOfPills><TotalDailyDose>5 mg</TotalDailyDose><Cost>$51 </Cost><DailyPills>1</DailyPills>

Prescriber Table:
<?xml version="1.0"?><Prescriber><PrescriberId>PSC001</PrescriberId><PrescriberName>Wayne</PrescriberName><Prescriber_Address>7 Elgar Center</Prescriber_Address><City>Chicago</City><State>Illinois</State>

Comment: Yes but how do I get it in that form ? 
I am using a mysql database, is there any tool that would make the data from database into triples for marklogic ? other than d2rq?

Comment: The output of d2rq looks pretty decent to me. If you dislike the file:// prefix, then add preprocessing to replace that with something else. Or just use sparql prefixes to abbreviate that..